# Typescript "Object is possibly 'null'" false alarm

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
isEmpty(vehicle: VehicleTitle) {
    return this.options && this.options[vehicle.type] && this.options[vehicle.type].length === 0;
}
```

The IDE (VSCode) points to `this.options[vehicle.type].length` and says

> Object is possibly 'null'

Don't you think this is a false alarm? What is wrong here?

**EDIT**

Minimal reproducible example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=8&ssc=31&pln=8&pc=37#).

Comment: Are you misreading the error? Because if `isEmpty` is supposed to return a boolean, it *could* also return `null` if it short-circuits earlier. And null is not the same as boolean. That might be the error here but I'm just guessing.

Comment: No, the error is exactly what I said. Besides, you are right that the return type is not correct for `isEmpty`.

Comment: [I cannot recreate it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGoQBbAQGwgFWDD2QG8AoZK5MATwAcIAuZAZzClAHNyBfc8rjitWyAKphgOMpWoB7epLkhWLUsgDaAawi0W7TiC4BdFhuPJeyALxl+1ZLKrBWAUQC2i2gAoAbpmw8FnQsXAIiPABKGQcHKAgwAFcoEBosVgA6BSUVZAAyPLSXLMVgZVYNf1C8DLpGCwKizOyylUqAsNqGCGMMvCMwDBtrWwAGAG4nSz5yIA). Can you include a [mcve]?

Comment: Hmm, I *can* recreate it [if I do this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGoQBbAQGwgFWDD2QG8AoZK5MATwAcIAuZAZzClAHNyBfc8rjitWyAKphgOMpWoB7epLkhWLUsgDaAawi0W7TiC4BdFhuPIAPshABXHNN7IAvGX7VksqsFYBRALaKtAAUAG6Y2Hgs6Fi4BER4AJQyHh5QEGC2UCA0WKwAdApKKsgAZKW5PoWKwMqsGuGxePl0jBbllQVFtSoNEXEtDBDG+XhGYBguzq4ADADcXsj8-EA). But I'm not sure if that's your case.

Comment: The error is comming from vetur, the plugin for vue development on VSCode.

Comment: @VLAZ I think this is the case. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=8&ssc=31&pln=8&pc=37#

Comment: vehicle could be null

Comment: @Ahmad I think something is wrong with your repro link

Comment: @JaredSmith I think the link OK.

Comment: @griFlo to, it cannot. Unless the `strict` check is disabled in the compiler (not recommended), then `vehicle` should be a `VehicleTitle` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## This seems like a bug in TypeScript!

[Here is a previous bug along these lines](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28081) That bug was *fixed* in July 2019 but the behaviour that was affected was:

```
const obj: { [key: string]: any[] | null }  = { prop: [] };

obj["prop"] && obj["prop"].length; //error
obj.prop && obj.prop.length; //OK
```

Since version 3.6.0 that's no longer the case and both lines are accepted. It seems that now there is a ever so slightly different issue but the outline is the same:

```
const obj: { [key: string]: any[] | null }  = { prop: [] };

const key = "prop" as const;
obj[key] && obj[key].length; //error
obj.prop && obj.prop.length; //OK
```

When using any variable, even a constant, to do the property access then TypeScript reports the same error as before.

There is a [similar older bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530) that is to do with bracket notation in general not being treated the same as dot notation. That one had been closed in August 2018 but has been reopened 12 days ago (Match 2020). It appears like this the team is aware of this problem and are revisiting the latter issue for a fix.

In the meantime, here are few ways to avoid the compilation error:

## Use a non-null assertion

You can simply do a [non-null assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-type-assertions) using the postfix `!` operator and you will correct the problem:

```js
isEmpty(vehicle: VehicleTitle) {
  return this.options && this.options[vehicle.type] && this.options[vehicle.type]!.length === 0;
//                                                                               ^
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=10&ssc=6&pln=8&pc=5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGoQBbAQGwgFWDD2QG8AoZK5MATwAcIAuZAZzClAHNyBfc8rjitWyAKphgOMpWoB7epLkhWLUsgDaAawi0W7TiC4BdFnBC0Nx5AB9kIAK45pvZAF4y-asllVgrAFEAW0VaAAoAN0xsPBZ0LFwCIjwAShlvbygIMAcoEBosVgA6BSUVZAAyCoL-EsVgZVYNKIS8IrpGayqa4tKGlWboxPaGCGMAQiK8IzAMdzcPAAYAbl9kfl4gA)

## Use an intermediate variable for the check

If you want to avoid the assertion, you can just fetch the value and then use it. That will assure the compiler that you aren't actually fetching two different values:

```
isEmpty(vehicle: VehicleTitle) {
  const value = this.options && this.options[vehicle.type];
  return value && value.length === 0;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGoQBbAQGwgFWDD2QG8AoZK5MATwAcIAuZAZzClAHNyBfc8rjitWyAKphgOMpWoB7epLkhWLUsgDaAawi0W7TiC4BdFnBC0Nx5AB9kIAK45pvZAF4y-asllVgrAFEAW0VaAAoAN0xsPBZ0LFwCIjwAShlvbwRldmQIuBwHFA8wLFYAOgUlFWQAMhqaUorFYGyNKIS8MrpGYwBuXwyoCDAHKBBc-MLa+ryCiDK8IxL3Nw8ABn7vfl4gA)

## Use optional chaining

Typescript also has a feature that will do the same check for you, called [optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-type-assertions). It's a postfix `?` after each property that might not exist:

```
isEmpty(vehicle: VehicleTitle) {
  return this.options?.[vehicle.type]?.length === 0;
//                   ^               ^
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGoQBbAQGwgFWDD2QG8AoZK5MATwAcIAuZAZzClAHNyBfc8rjitWyAKphgOMpWoB7epLkhWLUsgDaAawi0W7TiC4BdFnBC0Nx5AB9kIAK45pvW-afSAvGX7VksqmBWAFEAW0VaAAoAN0xsPBZ0LFwCIjwAShk-PygIMAcoEBosVgA6BSUVAH5SjVjkvFK6RmMavCMwDGRPHuQABgBuAOR+XiA)

Comment: Couldn't you say the same thing about the newly added lines of code? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGoQBbAQGwgFWDD2QG8AoZK5MATwAcIAuZAZzClAHNyBfc8rjitWyAMpgMZfoJzDRAVTDAcZStQD29ZRpCsWpZAG0A1hFot2nEFwC6LCRiO3kAH2QgArjlW9kAXml1KmDkYFYAUQBbbVoACgA3TGw8FnQsXAIiPABKNWoC5CgIME8oEBosVgA6LR09ZAAyRsrw2u1gXVYjJIy8arpGF2bWmrrOvR7kzIGGCFtqvBtJAP9AgAYAblCZAtYNKJKsGwicVgg4vIpC6mLS8tH2+tERyTbxrur2KVeqp4mat9FhBlhhtgV+PwgA

Comment: @Ahmad OK...well, I suppose the compiler treats bracket access differently, then. If so, the reason why it doesn't work is even more inane - it assumes that `vehicle.type` can change between the two calls, not the object retrieved. It's still TECHNICALLY possible using getters just like I showed in the answer but this makes even less sense than before, I think.

Comment: @Ahmad OK, so, it's not even a problem of this being `vehicle.type`. [I changed it to a constant](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGoQBbAQGwgFWDD2QG8AoZK5MATwAcIAuZAZzClAHNyBfc8rjitWyAMpgMZfoJzDRAVTDAcZStQD29ZRpCsWpZAG0A1hFot2nEFwC6LCRiO3kAH2QgArjlW9kAXml1KmDkYFYAUQBbbVoACgA3TGw8FnQsXAIiPABKNWoC5ARddmQ4AOQkjLwAOjpGAG5QgqgIME8oEBosVhqtHT1kADIh7vC+7WASozgXEbHe-qm9GdsavBtJAP9AgAYmgpkC1g0otqwbCJxWCDi8ikLqVvbOhYmB0XnJcaWSmvYpF8eu9lr0AesIJsMAdqPxeEA) and it's still complaining. I'm puzzled. I'll try to find more.

Comment: @Ahmad OK, found the reason. Now it makes sense why it makes no sense - [it's a bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28081)... I'll amend my answer in light of this.

Comment: @Ahmad wait...I'm now even more confused. The issue was closed and apparently fixed. I tried the reproduction code from the bug thread and it doesn't raise an error any more. But it *does* if you use a variable instead of a constant - what you are experiencing. So, `obj["prop"] && obj["prop"].length` - OK, `obj.prop && obj.prop.length` - OK, however `const p = "prop"; obj[p] && obj[p].length` - error. Even setting `const p = "prop" as const` doesn't change that. Really weird. I think there is still a bug here, I'll have to look into it more.

Comment: Do you think I have to file it as a bug?

Comment: @Ahmad I'm looking for duplicates myself and if I don't find anything I'd definitely submit it.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Also I think the answer needs an update.

Comment: @Ahmad done. I did find some stuff. I'll lave a comment instead of doing a full report. It seems the TS team is aware.