# Fix TypeScript errors after manually checking for Array.isArray

Tags: typescript

I have some class with the following definition:

```
export class WorkspaceFilter {
  [key: string]: boolean | string | [string]
}
```

Then I try to use it in the following function:

```
const fn = (filter: WorkspaceFilter, key: string) => {
  if (Array.isArray(filter[key]) {
    console.log(filter[key].length)
  }
}
```

The error is `Property 'length' does not exist on type 'false'.`
Obviously, that's because boolean is one of the accepted types. But I'm checking the type manually! How to shut up Typescript after that exact js type check?

Comment: I suspect it's more of a problem that you use `filter[key]` and TS things it *might* be a different key. Extract to a local variable `const myFilter = filter[key]` and use that

Comment: I think this might be the [same bug as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60847315/typescript-object-is-possibly-null-false-alarm/)

Answer (score 1):

if you check for it to be an array, you can tell typescript that it's dealing with an array:

```
export class WorkspaceFilter {
  [key: string]: boolean | string | [string]
}

const fn = (filter: WorkspaceFilter, key: string) => {
  if (Array.isArray(filter[key])) {
    console.log((filter[key] as string[]).length)
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works. But am I the only one who finds that a bit stupid? Typescript does not help here - if I remove Array.isArray condition and pass boolean, the code will throw an error. Typescript does not help here in any way, it's just an obstacle.