# Typescript: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: typescript

I have a set of basic function:

```
export function isObject(value: any): value is Object {
  return value !== null && typeof value === 'object' && !isArray(value);
}

export function isNumber(value: any): value is number {
  return typeof value === 'number' && !isNaN(value);
}

export function isString(value: any): value is string {
  return typeof value === 'string';
}

export function isArray(value: any): value is Array<any> {
  return Array.isArray(value);
}

export function isNull(value: any): value is null {
  return value === null;
}

export function isUndefined(value: any): value is undefined {
  return value === undefined;
}

export function isNullOrUndefined(value: any): value is null | undefined {
  if (isNull(value) || isUndefined(value)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

and a "special function" that check if a value is `null`, `undefined` or `empty` (empty string, 0 for number, empty array or empty object `{}`):

```
export function isNullOrUndefinedOrEmpty(value: any): value is null | undefined | '' | [] | {} | 0 {
  if (isNullOrUndefined(value)) {
    return true;
  }
  if (isString(value)) {
    return value === '';
  }
  if (isNumber(value)) {
    return value === 0;
  }
  if (typeof value === 'number' && isNaN(value)) {
    return true;
  }
  if (isArray(value)) {
    return value.length <= 0;
  }
  if (isObject(value)) {
    return Object.keys(value).length === 0 && value.constructor === Object;
  }
  return false;
}
```

when i use `isNullOrUndefinedOrEmpty()` typescript show the error:

> Property 'length' does not exist on type 'never', example:

```
export function foo(myArray: Array<any>): Array<any> {
  if (isNullOrUndefinedOrEmpty(myArray)) {
    return myArray;
  }
  // on myArray: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'never'
  for (let i = 0, e = myArray.length; i < e; i++) {
    // ... some logic
  }
  return myArray;
}
```

what i'm doing wrong?

[online demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=12&ssc=9&pln=12&pc=42#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEWIhACgFsBPAQSigEMSAuOC6kgHipRID4BKexm19hzgBvALAAoOHEwI4BTAGcAckgA2qgPJQAqigAmwBJhTA9WgKJEwMEsXKUaXLiIlSpUYDCRRcpPiQBuVzgAX2CAenC4HDg-Bzo4AAUoCDBgWBI4AHJVYBQAcxgACyy4PQhgBTgUCHhQRXgYmzTskwA3dKzghGg5XPhMOABeOAAGABo4YGHY%20yYAOlyC4oDpOGYp1cwAam3nMUk3SLh507gFCCJp1Qh8zDRgsMOPLx9Z-yDxJ4kDNFUqDyIVAYbC4RQqdRaXQGIwmMxQSzWWxtKiqJDAehsEg8OAotHTRTVNSqOAAHzgqBhxlMZOypXJAG0ALq00a04RPIA)

Comment: The problem is with the `{}` type. But I'm not sure why - [removing it from the `isNullOrUndefinedOrEmpty` signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEWIhACgFsBPAQSigEMSAuOC6kgHipRID4BKexm19hzgBvALAAoOHEwI4BTAGcAckgA2qgPJQAqigAmwBJhTA9WgKJEwMEsXKUaXLiIlSpUYDCRRcpPiQBuVzgAX2CAenC4HDg-Bzo4AAUoCDBgWBI4AHJVYBQAcxgACyy4PQhgBTgUCHhQRXgYmzTskwA3dKzghGg5XPhMOABeOAAGABo4YGHY+yYAOlyC4oDpOGYp1cwAam3nMUk3SLh507gFCCJp1Qh8zDRgsMOPLx9Z-yDxJ4kDNFUqDyIVAYbC4RQqdRaXQGIwmMxQSzWWxtKiqJDAehsEg8OAotHTRTVNSqOAAHzgqBhxlMZOypXJAG0ALq00YSIA) immediately removes the error.

Comment: there is an alternative signature for empty object?

Comment: That's what I expected it to be but also there is something weird going with the typings. If you remove the empty object from the signature and if the type guard *passes* (inside the `if`), the type of `myArray` is determined to be `myArray: (any[] & "") | (any[] & 0) | (any[] & [])` I have no explanation for what's happening or why. The type guard seems to be enriching the type with more possibilities rather than just narrowing.

Comment: ok, thanks.. maybe this is the case for opening an issue on typescript's github

Comment: Perhaps there already is one. But I'd suggest waiting a bit - it's possible that I don't understand how type guards work and this is the intended behaviour. Hopefully somebody comes and posts an answer to that effect. But it might also be a bug [wouldn't be a first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60848008/)

Comment: @VLAZ that type looks correct to me, albeit more complex than necessary—it simplifies to `myArray: []`

Comment: @LambdaFairy I'd have expected TS to prune the types that shouldn't be there, like `0` or empty string. But I also thought that producing `any[] & {}` was somehow a problem, not realising *why* that it makes the check too wide. I just thought it's messing up something else about the typings.

Answer (score 4):

In TypeScript, `{ foo: any; bar: any }` means "any value that has *at least* properties `foo` and `bar`". Notably, values with more properties will also fit that type.

It follows, then, that `{}` means "any value that has *at least* nothing". Since all values have at least nothing in them (even `null` and `undefined`), they will all fit the type. So after eliminating `{}` there is only the impossible case (`never`) left.

I don't know of a way to express "empty objects only" in TypeScript. But if you only call that function with arrays, then this signature can work instead:

```
function isNullOrUndefinedOrEmpty(x: any[]): x is null | undefined | [] {
```

Comment: "*It follows, then, that {} means "any value that has at least nothing".*" RIGHT! I somehow completely forgot that. Yes, `{}` wouldn't mean "empty object" but basically "any object" which makes the type guard over eager.

Comment: Yep, it's important to think of TypeScript types not as exact descriptions, but as a lower bound.