# Why I get: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

There is an array of objects in the redux store. When I would get it through `useSelector` there was no problem.
Then I extracted the code to a util function, and I used `store.getState()` so then I got the above error.
I've found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62280351/typescript-property-length-does-not-exist-on-type-never) so then I imported the array through args and I've putted in the types of the objects in the array a `length` property.
Now it works, but I don't like it like this.
Is there a way to get it from `store.getState()`?
Am I doing something wrong?

Minimal reproducible example, [here in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-carson-1gh0v?file=/src/QuestionsNum.tsx)

```js
export interface MultiQuestionProps {
  ...
  length: number;
}
```

```js
/* Pass questions as arg, to avoid TS error with length. */
const getDownloadedQuestionsNum = (
  // questionsMultiMixed: MultiQuestionProps,
  
) => {
  const { categoryId, gameTimer, gameType } = store.getState().general;

...

  const {
    questionsMultiMixed,
  } = store.getState().questions;

  let downloadedQuestionsNum = 0;

  if (gameType === constStr.multi) {
    switch (categoryId) {
      case constStr.mixed:
        if (gameTimer)
          downloadedQuestionsNum = questionsMultiMixed.length - indexMultiMixedWithTimer;
        else downloadedQuestionsNum = questionsMultiMixed.length - indexMultiMixedNoTimer;

...
```

```js
  setDownloadedQuestionsNum(getDownloadedQuestionsNum(
      questionsMultiMixed,

    ))
```

reducer

```js
interface InitialStateProps {
 
  questionsMultiMixed: MultiQuestionProps[];
 
}

const initialState: InitialStateProps = {
 
  questionsMultiMixed: [],
  ...
  
};
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mpgAaN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Hello @jcalz, I did what you asked, but I get two errors: `react-redux` does not export `useSelector` and `store.getState()` is not a function. If you can please solve these two, we might have a minimal reproducible example, [here in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-carson-1gh0v?file=/src/QuestionsNum.tsx) Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt that I'll be able to do much to get this into a reproducible state, since I am no expert at react.  Presumably the way to reproduce this is to remove code, not to add it, but that's up to you and depends on what demonstrates your problem most effectively.  I also don't think the division of labor with questions and answers would work out for me if I spent a lot of effort on improving others' questions, so I'm not particularly inclined to investigate too intently here.  Good luck!

Comment: I though the problem should include `redux`, since the error doesn't come up when I use `useSelector` but when I use `store.getState()`. That's why I added more code. Anyway, thanks for your time.